# RuntimeException : Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have got this type of error, How may I resolve this issue.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while
>   processing D:\Android
>   Project\AttendanceApp\app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_arrow_back.xml :
>   Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0

ic_arrow_back.xml

```
<vector android:height="@dimen/_25sdp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="@dimen/_25sdp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M20,11H7.83l5.59,-5.59L12,4l-8,8 8,8 1.41,-1.41L7.83,13H20v-2z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: post your ic_arrow_back.xml

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: did you enable vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add certain attributes on your app's build.gradle.

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

Comment: It's crazy how this is done by default in 2021

Answer (score 0):

try to enable `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary` in your build.gradle

```
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

and in your `layout.xml` :

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat ="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
        />
```